# jQuery waypoint.reached not triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to get started with jquery waypoint plugging, however I don't get the waypoint.reached callback triggering. Please take a look at my example at jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yAfhU/1/

The callback function gets not executed:

```
$('#wrapper').delegate('.waypoint', 'waypoint.reached', function (event, direction) {
  alert("test");
});
```

Comment: For starters, check your console output. The plugin throws the following error: "jQuery Waypoints needs a callback function or handler option."

Comment: That's not the problem. Anyway, I fixed it, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you read about this `waypoint.reached` event? I couldn't find *anything* about this in [the documentation](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) or [the source](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/blob/master/waypoints.coffee). You can't just make up an event name and expect it to work auto-magically.

According to [the documentation](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs), you need to pass the handler as first argument to `$.waypoint`:

```
$('.waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
    console.log("waypoint reached");
});
```

If you need to set other options as well, you can pass that object as a second argument or pass just the options object along with a `handler` property:

```
$('.waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
    console.log("waypoint reached");
}, {
    offset: 10
});
// or
$('.waypoint').waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
        console.log("waypoint reached");
    },
    offset: 10
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/6Ry5S/) Open up your console, scroll a bit and you should be getting log messages.

Comment: I have read about it in this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212331/triggering-jquery-flexslider-events-when-jquery-waypoint-is-reached Thank you Matthias, I will have a look.

Comment: Ah, seems like the waypoint.reached callback was in a older release and got removed. https://raw.github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/1.1/waypoints.min.js

Comment: @charihans That makes sense. Instead of triggering an event, the handler is now [manually called](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/blob/1b0520f02d47b6eefc82921625c2d0826838b1fd/waypoints.js#L238).